# Eventbrite - buy multiple tickets

Tags: eventbrite

Is it possible to use the APIs to do payments to multiple events with one call to eventbrite?

Answer (score 0):

Its actually not possible to purchase any tickets via the API. That work needs to be done by sending users to your Eventbrite event page.